# Sum of time difference - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

I have a table:

table1

```
col1    start_date_time                 end_date_time
Test1   01-06-19 11:43:35.927422000 AM  01-06-19 11:44:20.127907000 AM
Test2   01-06-19 11:44:28.703518000 AM  01-06-19 11:45:06.538883000 AM
Test3   01-06-19 11:42:18.784477000 AM  01-06-19 11:42:27.635102000 AM
```

I wrote a query which gives me the time difference:

```
select a.*, end_date_time - start_date_time exec_time from table1 a
order by exec_time desc;
```

Output Table

```
col1    start_date_time                 end_date_time                   exec_time
Test1   01-06-19 11:43:35.927422000 AM  01-06-19 11:44:20.127907000 AM  +00 00:00:44.200485
Test2   01-06-19 11:44:28.703518000 AM  01-06-19 11:45:06.538883000 AM  +00 00:00:37.835365
Test3   01-06-19 11:42:18.784477000 AM  01-06-19 11:42:27.635102000 AM  +00 00:00:08.850625
```

I need the sum like 00:01:29.

How can I sum the exec_time in SQL? I need to find the total time based.

Comment: Hi. I'm not super familiar with Oracle SQL, but would the EXTRACT() function help? You could then subquery the time difference and rejoin into table1 to get a SUM.  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm

Comment: If it can be accurate, that would be perfect!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle does not support the aggregation of interval datatypes, which is a crying shame because that would be the easiest way to solve problems like this. However, [the fiendish mind of Stew Ashton came up with a solution](https://community.oracle.com/ideas/2903) of converting intervals into numbers and back again.

```
select numtodsinterval(  
  sum(  
    (sysdate+(end_date_time - start_date_time) - sysdate) * 24 * 60 * 60
        + extract(second from (end_date_time - start_date_time)) 
              - trunc(extract(second from (end_date_time - start_date_time))) -- (*)
  )  
  , 'second'  
)  
from table1;
```

Here is [a demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=63c3b728bc18fb7fd919011a89fd7699).

(*) This line makes the answer accurate to microseconds.

Comment: Thank you. Although this one is entirely down to Stew. It seems like you're working on something pretty interesting.

Comment: Yeah, it is pretty interesting stuff, quite complex though. Thanks again for your help.